# Switch Statements for Grades Javascript

Tags: javascript

So I have to get the grade from a prompt then produce an alert box that says something about the grade using switch statements. This is what i have so far but it just tells me back the grade I have given it if i add an alert box at the bottom

```
    var grade = prompt("What grade did you get for the assessment?");

switch(grade) {
    case 0: "A" = ("Excellent"); break;
    case 1: "B" = "Very Good"; break;
    case 2: "C" = "Good"; break;
    case 3: "D" = "Pass"; break;
    case 4: "E" = "Almost a pass"; break;
    case 5: "F" = "Fail"; break;
    default : "Please enter a grade from A-F";
}
```

Comment: And your question/issue is?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: You don’t seem to understand the syntax of switch statements. Google it and look it up.

Comment: Have you googled it ?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_prompt

Comment: Switch statements http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

Comment: Why all the hate? He has an issue and needs help

Comment: @samrodrigues - i see you asked a few questions in the past. Did you not google them? We all come here to learn. We should all try and remember that we all knew little once upon a time too :)

Comment: @darren Well its just a question and i did provide resources to help him  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your switch statement is a little messed up.

I won't post full code for you. I always find typing out, rather than copy/pasting helps with the learning and memory retention, though you would be looking for something a little more like this:

```
var grade = prompt("What grade did you get for the assessment?");
var result; // this will hold a result from our switch

switch(grade){
 case "A": // this is what will be typed (case sensitive)
    result = "Excellent"; // assign some text to result - no brackets
    break;
case "B": // this is what will be typed (case sensitive)
    result = "Very good";
    break;
default:
    result = "please enter.." //something wasn't matched   
}
console.log(result); // spits out the result var
```

To break the switch down:

```
switch(yourVar)
```

you pass in yourVar to the switch for evaluation

```
case "D":
//
break;
```

When `yourVar` == "D" do whatever is between case and break

```
default:
//..
```

When there is no match use whatever is after default.

Answer (score 0):

```
var grade = prompt("What grade did you get for the assessment?");

var message;

switch (grade) {
    case "A":
        message = "Excellent";
        break;

    case "B":
        message = "Very Good";
        break;

    case "C":
        message = "Good";
        break;

    case "D":
        message = "Pass";
        break;

    case "E":
        message = "Almost a pass";
        break;

    case "F":
        message = "Fail";
        break;

    default:
        message = "Please enter a grade from A-F";
}  

alert(message);
```